# Sorting list of data Python

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I need some help with sorting the list of duplicates within the list that contains even more data. Basically what I get when I run def which is empty.

```
pprint.pprint(response)
([], [], [], [])
```

After I fill it with data:

```
pprint.pprint(response)
([],
 [],
 [],
 [{u't_ids': [],
 u'id': u'1',
 u'users': [{u'favorite': u'One',
             u'id': u'123456789',
             u'nemesis': u'Red'},
            {u'favorite': u'Two',
             u'id': u'987654321',
             u'nemesis': u'Blue'}],
 u'topic': u'FavNem'}])
```

So now the tricky part. If i by chance have more of the lists inside this last(forth) list. I want to get rid of duplicates. Since they will generate a response that would look like this:

```
pprint.pprint(response)
([],
 [],
 [],
 [{u't_ids': [],
 u'id': u'1',
 u'users': [{u'favorite': u'One',
             u'id': u'123456789',
             u'nemesis': u'Red'},
            {u'favorite': u'Two',
             u'id': u'987654321',
             u'nemesis': u'Blue'}],
 u'topic': u'FavNem1'}]{u't_ids': [],
 u'id': u'2',
 u'users': [{u'favorite': u'One',
             u'id': u'123456789',
             u'nemesis': u'Red'},
            {u'favorite': u'Two',
             u'id': u'987654321',
             u'nemesis': u'Blue'},
            {u'favorite': u'Three',
             u'id': u'555555555',
             u'nemesis': u'Yellow'}],
 u'topic': u'FavNem2'}])
```

My goal is to get this outcome:

note: It's called response2 and it may/may not have other 3 empty, I can embed the response2 as fifth list. If you see what I'm aiming at.

```
pprint.pprint(response2)
([], 
 [],
 [],
 [{u't_ids': [],
 u'id': u'1',
 u'users': [{u'favorite': u'One',
             u'id': u'123456789',
             u'nemesis': u'Red'},
            {u'favorite': u'Two',
             u'id': u'987654321',
             u'nemesis': u'Blue'}],
 u'topic': u'FavNem1'}]{u't_ids': [],
 u'id': u'2',
 u'users': [{u'favorite': u'Three',
             u'id': u'555555555',
             u'nemesis': u'Yellow'}],
 u'topic': u'FavNem2'}])
```

So basically if I have even more copies in new topics "FavNem3,4,5," I will get only the ones I already didn't pull out.

Note: List doesn't have to be sorted and should focus on speed (eg. if I have 5000 users and 2000 topics)

I have some "solutions" which are far from actual fix.. 
Any ideas or guidance would be appreciated.